# unrelated undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am new to rails and have been working to build my application so forgive me if this error appears to be basic.  I had recently been working with devise to add a form field called "birthday" to devise.  In doing so, I accidentally committed it wrong, and had to commit it again.  Eventually I got it working.

However, when I go to a different part of my code, when I go to post a "pin", I get an error 
"undefined method `birthday' for #" even though birthday is completly unrelated to the pin, and shouldn't be causing the error.

Is there still a problem in my database?  How does this occur.

The error line is:
  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.new(pin_params)

I haven't been able to figure out how to solve this.

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome! Ruby on Rails is an awesome thing to work in! It gets really frustrating at times, so I hope stuff like this wouldn't discourage you. Can you please copy and paste your error here? Thanks.

Comment: What is the content of `pin_params` when that error happens? Does it include `:birthday`?

Comment: What it returns to me the error is:  {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"4QLiaY7IuDeohulyRy/+zEpfj87iEuUjdPzfpA1pEhY=",
 "pin"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x46d5fb0 @tempfile=#<File:C:/Users/Brandon/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20131013-13636-1tdfu89>,
 @original_filename="S1050666 (1).JPG",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"pin[image]\"; filename=\"S1050666 (1).JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">,
 "image_remote_url"=>"",
 "description"=>"sdffds"},
 "commit"=>"Create Pin"}

Comment: I don't see birthday anywhere in there